# Monochromatic Solutions

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, terminology, ramsey-theory

I recently came across this paper: 
http://borisalexeev.com/pdf/foxgraham.pdf

"On Minimal Colorings Without Monochromatic Solutions
To a Linear Equation"

Can someone explain in clearer terms what it means for a linear equation to not have a monochromatic solution with minimal colorings?

Answer (score 3):

Let $C$ be a set of colors.  Suppose every integer is colored with one of the colors in $C$. Formally, this is just a mapping $\chi: \Bbb Z\to C$ that says, for each integer $i$, the color $\chi(i)$ of the integer $i$. This mapping is called a *coloring* of the integers. One could similarly consider colorings of $\Bbb R$ or whatever.

Now consider a linear equation, say $$x+y=z.$$ A  solution to the equation is a triple $\langle x, y, z\rangle$ of three numbers for which $x+y=z$.  If we have a coloring $\chi$ in mind, a *monochromatic* solution is a solution that has all three of $x,y,z$ the same color; that is $\chi(x) = \chi(y) = \chi(z)$.

Given a coloring, we can ask if the equation has a monochromatic solution; or given some set of colors we can ask if the equation has a monochromatic solution for *every* coloring with those colors.

[A theorem of Schur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_theorem#Ramsey_theory) solves the problem completely for the equation $x+y=z$, which has a monochromatic solution in integers for *any* coloring with *any* finite number of colors.  (Clearly, there may not be a monochromatic solution if the number of colors is infinite.)  For different equations, the answer is different.

Suppose some equation $E$ has  a monochromatic solution for every possible coloring of the integers with $p$ different colors, but there is some coloring $\chi$  with $p+1$ colors for which there is no monochromatic solution to $E$.

> Then this coloring $\chi$ is a minimal coloring without a monochromatic solution to the equation

which is your question. (The definition in the paper is at the top of page 2, labeled **Definition**.)